# Wifi and Ethernet unclaimed on ubuntu-based linux

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, ethernet, thinkpad

I'm trying to finish the installation of elementaryOS (an Ubuntu-based distribution) on a Thinkpad E460. However, I can't neither have Ethernet nor Wifi.
In fact, `lshw -c network -sanitize` shows both devices as `UNCLAIMED`.

I explain this by the version of the distribution which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 in April 2015 and the laptop seems quite recent. So, I think the kernel doesn't have drivers for this recent material.

The material is the following according to [Ubuntu's certifed hardware page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201507-18700/):

- Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V
- Intel Wireless 8260

How can I get these devices to work without an Internet connection on the laptop?

I did not use elementaryOS version from December 2015 because I encountered UEFI issues so I couldn't even install it.

Comment: To get more information , add the output of `lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally tried again to install elementaryOS with the iso of December 2015 and it worked after I've changed UEFI boot to legacy. After installation, the Ethernet port worked but still not the Wifi.

To make the Wifi work, I have upgraded the kernel from 3.19 to 4.3.0.

Now Ethernet and Wifi seem to work fine.